# A limit by using Taylor's expansion

Tags: real-analysis

Let us consider the following limit:

$$
\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x^2)-x+\frac{x^6}{6}-x^{10}}{x^{10}}
$$

I use the Taylor's series for $\sin(x^2)$ and, by doing computations I have
$$
\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2-x-\frac{119}{120}x^{10}+o(x^{10})}{x^{10}}
$$

The solution I have doesn't explain it, but asserts that the limit is exactly $-\frac{119}{120}$. May I use the fact that the numerator is asymptotically equivalent to $-\frac{119}{120}x^{10}$ in order to reduce it? It seems really strange. Or this limit goes to $\infty$, as I expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that 
$$\sin(x^2)-x+\frac{x^6}{6}-x^{10}=-x+o(x).$$
and the given limit is an undetermined infinity
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^{\pm}} \frac{\sin(x^2)-x+\frac{x^6}{6}-x^{10}}{x^{10}}=\mp\infty.$$
I guess that your limit is
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x^2)-x^2+\frac{x^6}{6}-x^{10}}{x^{10}}=
\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{x^{10}}{5!}-x^{10}+o(x^{10})}{x^{10}}=\frac{1}{5!}-1=\frac{119}{120}.$$

Comment: So, it goes to $\infty$ as I think?

Comment: In fact, I thought there was a mistake within the statement of the limit, too. Thank you!